# How to find all the opposite combinations between two columns in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am making a web dating app that needs to match users and let them chat with each other.

I want to figure out how to find all the matches for a particular user.

Right now I have a table called follows that has 2 columns.

```
UserID | MatchUserID
--------------------
1       | 2
2       | 1
1       | 3
1       | 4
1       | 5
4       | 1
5       | 4
```

The idea is that for two users to match they need to follow one another. The table above shows which user follows which.

Assuming that the user who is currently logged on is UserID = 1.
I need a query that will return from the MatchUserID table the following results:

2, 4

In a way, I am looking to find all the opposite combinations between the two columns.

This is the code I use to create the table.

```
CREATE TABLE Match
(
  UserID INT NOT NULL,
  MatchUserID INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (UserID, MatchUserID)
);
```

Comment: Is it not a simple self-join, joining left.UserId to right.MatchId and left.MatchId to right.UserId? That will give all mutually matched combinations, and then filter to the specific user you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a self join:

```
select m.MatchUserID
from `Match` m inner join `Match` mm
on mm.MatchUserID = m.UserId
where 
  m.UserId = 1
  and 
  m.MatchUserID = mm.UserId
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eoXZEgU52biKGSs3GcapGa/0).
Results:

```
| MatchUserID |
| ----------- |
| 2           |
| 4           |
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way possibly is to use `EXISTS` and a correlated subquery that searches for the other match.

```
SELECT t1.matchuserid
       FROM elbat t1
       WHERE t1.userid = 1
             AND EXISTS (SELECT *
                                FROM elbat t2
                                WHERE t2.matchuserid = t1.userid
                                      AND t2.userid = t1.matchuserid);
```